How do I fix this code to consolidate my google sheet notes?
I'm using Google Apps Script and I am trying to write a program that consolidates my monthly notes. I have hidden columns i-t which are labeled "January 2024" - "December 2024" chronologically. I have a dropdown configured in column H that shows "January 2024" - "December 2024" to select from.
The idea is to hide the 12 months of notes (which looks terrible on the sheet), and let me unhide a singular column of my choosing. "January 2024" from the dropdown, should unhide column i named "January 2024".
For some reason it's not doing anything. Not sure what to do.
Here's the code:
function onEdit(e) {
  // Ensure the function only runs during actual edits
  if (!e) return;  // If no event object (e), stop the execution to avoid errors

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  // Ensure the edit was made in column H (8th column) and after the header row
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 8 && e.range.getRow() > 1) {
    var selectedMonth = e.range.getValue(); // Get the value of the selected month

    // Define the mapping of months to columns
    var monthMapping = {
      "January 2024": 9,   // Column I
      "February 2024": 10, // Column J
      "March 2024": 11,    // Column K
      "April 2024": 12,    // Column L
      "May 2024": 13,      // Column M
      "June 2024": 14,     // Column N
      "July 2024": 15,     // Column O
      "August 2024": 16,   // Column P
      "September 2024": 17,// Column Q
      "October 2024": 18,  // Column R
      "November 2024": 19, // Column S
      "December 2024": 20  // Column T
    };

    // Notes columns from I to T (9 to 20)
    var notesColumnStart = 9;
    var notesEndColumn = 20;

    // Unhide all columns from I to T
    sheet.showColumns(notesColumnStart, notesEndColumn - notesColumnStart + 1);
    
    // Check if the selected month exists in the mapping
    if (selectedMonth in monthMapping) {
      var selectedColumn = monthMapping[selectedMonth]; // Get the corresponding column number
      
      // Check if the selected column is already visible
      var isColumnVisible = !sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(selectedColumn);
      
      if (isColumnVisible) {
        // If the column is visible, re-hide it (toggle behavior)
        sheet.hideColumns(selectedColumn);
        Logger.log("Hiding column: " + selectedColumn);
      } else {
        // If the column is hidden, show it and hide all others
        Logger.log("Showing column: " + selectedColumn);
        for (var col = notesColumnStart; col <= notesEndColumn; col++) {
          if (col !== selectedColumn) {
            sheet.hideColumns(col);  // Hide the column if it is not the selected month
          }
        }
        sheet.showColumns(selectedColumn); // Make sure the selected column is shown
      }
    } else {
      // If the selected month isn't in the mapping, log the issue
      Logger.log("Month not found in the mapping: " + selectedMonth);
    }
  }
}


The name is Google Apps Script. It's not a language. To learn more about it, please refer to https://developers.google.com/apps-script. Regarding the programming language, it's not Java; it's JavaScript.

Please add the execution logs.

OnEdit() Hide and Show Columns
I modified your script and you should be able to achieve what you like using this code.

You may try this:
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Define the mapping of months to columns
  var monthMapping = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

  // Notes columns from I to T (9 to 20)
  var notesColumnStart = 9;
  var notesEndColumn = 20;

  // Hide all columns from I to T
  sheet.hideColumns(notesColumnStart, notesEndColumn - notesColumnStart + 1);
  // Trigger Event
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 8 && e.range.getRow() == 1) {
    const date = e.range.getValue().getMonth();
    sheet.showColumns(monthMapping[date]);
  }
  
}


I refactored and removed the unnecessary lines which are no longer needed.


Sample Output:


Reference:

Simple Triggers
Arrays
Range


If you have questions regarding this answer, feel free to ask and comment.
